# Renaming ArcMap Legend item titles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend

My legend is currently displaying both the layer name and indented data name underneath the layer name. How to display just its name shown in the table of contents?

Answer (score 5):

Right Click on your **legend Graphic** > click **properties** > select the **items** tab > in the list of your layers select your required **layer(s)** > right click and go to its **properties** > select the **General** tab, from here you can mark check on whether you want a layer name or its indents or both.

Like:

[image]