# Changing legend item properties using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, legend

I'm developing a Python script to created several map document (.mxd) files from .shp file and .xlsx file automatically. After setting symbology of layer and changing labels, I want to hide heading of legend by working on "show heading" option on "Legend Item Properties", but unfortunately I cannot found this property. Here is part of my code:

```py
def CreateMXD(srcMXDDir, srcMXDName, srcSHPDir, srcLyrDir, srcStyleName, srcXlsxWB):
    srcLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(srcLyrDir)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(srcMXDDir + "//" + srcMXDName + '.mxd')
    mxdDF0 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    # mxdDF1 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd2, "Layers")[1]
    mxdLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(srcSHPDir)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(mxdDF0, mxdLayer, "TOP")
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", mxdDF0)[0]

    fields = arcpy.ListFields(srcSHPDir)
    for field in fields:
        fieldType = field.type
        fieldName = field.name
        if fieldType in ["Double", "Integer", "Long"] and fieldName.startswith('edu'):
            arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(mxdDF0, addLayer, srcLayer, True)
            # print(addLayer.symbologyType)
            if addLayer.symbologyType == 'GRADUATED_COLORS':
                addLayer.symbology.valueField = fieldName
                labels = addLayer.symbology.classBreakLabels
                try:
                    addLayer.symbology.classBreakLabels = ["{} - {}".format(*r)
                                                                         for r in [
                                                                             [round(float(f), 2) for f in lab.split(" - ")]
                                                                             for lab in labels
                                                                         ]
                                                                         ]
                except:
                    print('Error in Symbology | %s' % fieldName)
```

[This link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292805/renaming-arcmap-legend-item-titles) has described this functionality in ArcMap but I want to do this change using ArcPy scripting. Below you can see the screen of my MXD file and mentioned option in ArcMap:

[image: Arcmap show heading option]

Answer (score 1):

Using ArcGIS 10.4 (not Pro version), I did this by defining new `style` and then updating `legend`. So by double-click on labels in legend an going to `Legend Properties > Style... > Properties...` I could turn `Show Heading` option off. After applying changes, I named it **df0_legend_style** and saved it as a new `style`. Below image shows how we can create new style in ArcMap:

[image]

When I created the style, I added these codes to my script:

```py
newStyle = arcpy.mapping.ListStyleItems("USER_STYLE", "Legend Items", df0_legend_style)[0]
mxd_legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
mxd_legend.title = ""
mxd_legend.updateItem(addLayer, newStyle)
mxd.saveACopy('newMXD.mxd')
```

This code update Legend Item by newly created style.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346089/changing-legend-item-properties-using-arcpy/346230#comment565631_346089):

> ArcPy does *not* support all ArcObjects functionality, especially with
>   regard to mapping and symbology.

In ArcGIS Pro there is an [ItemGroup class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/itemgroup-class.htm#D_GUID-58BD0136-66A1-4C53-B28E-B6F52FFA3FFC) and:

> The ItemGroup class allows you to change a heading value for a group
>   and more importantly provides access to the individual items in each
>   group.

However, the ItemGroup class appears to only be available for a UniqueValuesRenderer.

Since you are using ArcMap and a GraduatedColorsRenderer, the above will not provide a solution but it may provide some ideas about where to look for the functionality you seek within ArcGIS Desktop when you are using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro.